# Heading with medium border bottom - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is possible using Bootstrap, add a border bottom with 3rem of width (for example) with a class, and add the parameter of color in the tag? Example:

```
.half-title:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: .75rem;
    background: Red;
}

<h1 class="half-title">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
```

OK. But I want something like this:

```
.half-title:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: .75rem;
}

<h1 class="half-title bg-red">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
```

Is this possible?
Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/m3ydro1q/1/

Comment: Your question is not clear on how the output exactly should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **focus.style** for your suggestion regarding using codes snippet to better demonstrate the result.

Change the **background-color** and instead use **border** for your underline, then you'll be able to use Bootstrap classes to change the underline colour.

```css
.half-title:after{
    border: solid 4px transparent;
    border-color: inherit;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: .75rem;
    width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<h1 class="half-title border-default">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>

<h1 class="half-title border-info">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>

<h1 class="half-title border-warning">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>

<h1 class="half-title border-danger">THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
```

Comment: Hi! Good answer, but I think, it requires more explanation, if this task can be solved using Bootstrap, or not, and why. Although try to use code Snippet, to demonstrate your result. to add Bootstrap classed to snippet you can use CDNs, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

Comment: Perfect for me ActiveCodex. Thank you.